# Getting city names from CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios

I'm using CLLocationManager on iOS to get the location of my device.

Is there a way to get the city name.. e.g.:

> Amsterdam
>
> Utrecht

instead of coordinates such as:

> <+45.80397963, +13.50200231> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course
> -1.00) @ 14/09/11 22:47:42 Ora Legale Europa Centrale

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is reverse geocode. You may want to use an instance of MKReverseGeocoder, but there's restrictions about when you may use it. If you aren't going to show result on a map, you'll have to use some web based reverse geocode service.